# Trying to get a Dymo 4XL to work using a Pi Zero W as a print server

Tags: networking, server, printing

I'm so lost. I don't know what to do.

I followed [these instructions](https://chicagodist.com/blogs/news/15272985-using-the-raspberry-pi-as-a-print-server-for-a-dymo-4xl-label-printer?comment=22650126415#comments) until I got to the part where it had me download the SDK. I didn't know how to follow the steps after that.

So, what I did was followed [these instructions](https://www.hmazter.com/2013/05/raspberry-pi-printer-server-for-labelwriter/) after that, up until it had me add the printer. Instead I followed the old instructions after that and did it through the web interface. However, when I go to add the printer, it doesn't have the dymo 4xl listed as a model. It only has one model and that's "dymo label printer (en)".

So...what should I do? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your first link the SDK part has an incorrect link. Try downloading the file from:

http://www.dymo.com/en-US/dymo-label-sdk-and-cups-drivers-for-linux-dymo-label-sdk-cups-linux-p--1#

After you download the file you will need to extract the drivers as follows:

```
tar zxvf dymo-cups-drivers-1.4.0.tar.gz
```

That will create a `dymo-cups-drivers-1.4.0.5` folder, then you should be able to continue on with your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI: If you need a label printer, do not buy a DYMO from this point in time onwards.

I have contacted their customer support and although not properly mentioned on their website, they have stopped supporting Linux as of this point in time.